# null coalesce operator into if statement

Tags: php, ternary-operator

below my code using the new php null coalesce.

```
($i[$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ?? '/']  ?? $i[''])();
```

I want to convert into if statement. can anybody help me pls?thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are going to take your code and give it a better look.

```
// Your code
($i[$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ?? '/']  ?? $i[''])();
```

What whe are actually saying here is `if (is_null($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']))` so what we can effectively do is simply reform your code.

```
if (is_null($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) {
    if (is_null($i['/'])) {
        $i['']();
    } else {
        $i['/']();
    }
} else {
    if (is_null($i[$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']])) {
        $i['']();
    } else {
        $i[$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']]();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Peter, but I'm getting this error unexpected '{'

Comment: @JulyPalomiano Just change `if (is_null($i[$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']]) {` to `if (is_null($i[$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']])) {` ?

Comment: @JulyPalomiano I'm sorry. I made a Typo